# Delphi FMX MapView - remove all markers

Tags: android, delphi, google-maps-markers, android-mapview, firemonkey

I have TMapView and placed some TMapMarkerDescriptors on it using MapView1.AddMarker(...), but how I can clear map (remove all placed marers) from it ?

I cant find something as MapView.Clear in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

okay this works fine

```
var
   mar : array of  TMapMarker;

procedure TForm1.clear_markers;
var
i:integer;
begin
 if high(mar) > -1 then
  for i:=0 to high(mar) do
    if Assigned(mar[i]) then
     mar[i].Remove;

setlength(mar,0);
end;
```

Markers was placed by this code in loop.
Variables *loc* and *s* are  loaded from database

```
setlength(mar,length(mar)+1);
Descr := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(loc, s);
mar[high(mar)]:=MapView1.AddMarker(Descr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have to remove each marker individually as far as I can tell, which means you'll have to store references to the TMapMarker objects you've created. TMapMarker (the result of the MapView1.AddMarker call) has two methods. "Remove" removes the marker from the map, while "DisposeOf" will remove the marker from the map and free the TMapMarker object.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to add that there seems no viable way to get access to the collection of markers managed by the Android map view implementation in order to iterate meaningfully across them and remove them (at least, not without inappropriate levels of unmaintainable tomfoolery).

Comment: My problem is that: I have stored coordinates of markers in database, sometimes is necessary to refresh map from actual state in database.

How I can store references to added markers ?